# Cumulocity - How to clear Events for a specific device via REST?

Tags: cumulocity

How can I clear/delete all events for a specific device and a specific event type? I tried the a `DELETE .../event/events?source=123456&type=c8y_LocationUpdate` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass deletion of events is not allowed. Only one event can be deleted at a time with:

```
DELETE .../event/events/<id>
```

Alternatively retention rules can be set to delete events older than X days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it isn't working for you but I delete my events using the syntax you provided, d4rty:

```
DELETE <tenant ID>/event/events?source=12345
```

and it's working just fine.